# How to explode pd.Series and concat to column in Pandas without duplicating other column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The issue starts with how my excel file is read into Pandas.

|  | id | name | application | new_applications |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 451124577 | ABC123 | app.1 | [app.10, app.20] |
| 1 |  |  | app.2 |  |
| 2 | 845151514 | DEF456 | app.3 | [app.30, app.40] |
| 3 |  |  | app.4 |  |

When reading the file into Pandas there is a hierarchy but none of the cells are grouped or set as a multi-index.
Unfortunately our system requires this format so any changes I make have to maintain that format.

###### So far this is what I have:

```python
df1 =df[['id', 'name', 'application', 'new_applications']]

df1 = df.set_index(['id', 'name', 'application']).explode('new_applications')
```

##### Outcome:

| id | name | application |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 451124577 | ABC123 | app.1 |
|  | ABC123 | app.2 |
|  | ABC123 | app.10 |
|  | ABC123 | app.20 |
| 845151514 | DEF456 | app.3 |
|  | DEF456 | app.4 |
|  | DEF456 | app.30 |
|  | DEF456 | app.40 |

###### Also tried:

```python
df1 =df[['id', 'name', 'application', 'new_applications']]

temp_df = df['new_applications'].rename('application').explode()
df2 = pd.merge(df1, temp, left_index=True, right_index=True)

# and

df3 = pd.concat([df1, temp], axis=1)

# and

df10 = df1.set_index('id').join(temp.set_index('id'), rsuffix='_r')
# or
df10 = df1.join(temp.set_index('id'), on='id', rsuffix='_r')
```

##### Outcome Needed

| id | name | application |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 451124577 | ABC123 | app.1 |
|  |  | app.2 |
|  |  | app.10 |
|  |  | app.20 |
| 845151514 | DEF456 | app.3 |
|  |  | app.4 |
|  |  | app.30 |
|  |  | app.40 |

When I `reset_index()` I can't figure out a way to get replace all the duplicate values in columns `['id', 'name']` without dropping the entire row.

Nevertheless, I inevitably end up with the same issue.

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: @PierreD I need to write back to an excel file with the same format that it was read into Pandas but with the added values from the exploded series.. I edited the post so give a better visual.

Comment: Oh, you mean in the excel sheet `A1=451124577` but `A2` is literally blank (avoid repeating `A1`). So it has a visual hierarchy of sorts. But the column `new_applications`, when blank, really means blank? What is `df.to_dict(orient='list')` in your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can groupby the cumsum of `id` and `name` columns, then concat value in `new_applications` columns to `application` column in each group.

```py
df_ = (df.groupby([df['id'].notna().cumsum(), df['name'].notna().cumsum()]).apply(lambda group: pd.concat([group, pd.DataFrame({'application': group['new_applications'].iloc[0]})])))
```

```
print(df_)

                    id    name application  new_applications
id name
1  1    0  451124577.0  ABC123       app.1  [app.10, app.20]
        1          NaN     NaN       app.2               NaN
        0          NaN     NaN      app.10               NaN
        1          NaN     NaN      app.20               NaN
2  2    2  845151514.0  DEF456       app.3  [app.30, app.40]
        3          NaN     NaN       app.4               NaN
        0          NaN     NaN      app.30               NaN
        1          NaN     NaN      app.40               NaN
```

Then drop the multilevel index, reset the index and drop the `new_applications` column.

```py
df_.index = df_.index.droplevel()
df_ = df_.reset_index(drop=True).drop('new_applications', axis=1)
```

```
print(df_)

            id    name application
0  451124577.0  ABC123       app.1
1          NaN     NaN       app.2
2          NaN     NaN      app.10
3          NaN     NaN      app.20
4  845151514.0  DEF456       app.3
5          NaN     NaN       app.4
6          NaN     NaN      app.30
7          NaN     NaN      app.40
```

Comment: This works great! I was finally able to achieve my desired outcome after @PierreD gave me the idea of using 'to_dict'. 
I ended up using df.itertuples() to append to a list based on index and then constructing the DataFrame, but in the long term I wanted something I could use across our entire application file which will soon enough be in the 100k+ rows range.

Comment: I'm definitely going to have to try and get my head wrapped around your answer to fully understand what's happening! Thank you!